# RE match fail in python, confuse with the result on regex101

Tags: python, regex

http://regex101.com/r/oU6eI5/1 , test here seam works, but when i put in Python, match whole str.

```
str = galley/files/tew/tewt/tweqt/
re.sub('^.+/+([^/]+/$)', "\1", str)
```

i want get "tweqt/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better if you define the pattern or regex as raw string.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "galley/files/tew/tewt/tweqt/"
>>> m = re.sub(r'^.+/+([^/]+/$)', r'\1', s)
               ^                  ^
>>> m
'tweqt/'
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a raw string in the replace:

```
str = galley/files/tew/tewt/tweqt/
re.sub('^.+/+([^/]+/$)', r"\1", str)
#                        ^
```

Otherwise, you get the escaped character `\1`. For instance on my console, it's a little smiley.

If you somehow don't want to raw your string, you'll have to escape the backslash:

```
re.sub('^.+/+([^/]+/$)', "\\1", str)
```

Also worth noting that it's a good practice to raw your regex strings and use consistent quotes, so you I would advise using:

```
re.sub(r'^.+/+([^/]+/$)', r'\1', str)
```

---

**Other notes**

It might be simpler to match (using `re.search`) instead of using `re.sub`:

```
re.search(r'[^/]+/$', str).group()
# => tweqt/
```

And you might want to use another variable name other than `str` because this will override the existing function `str()`.

Comment: works， thanks a lot.  the code generated by regex101 miss "r"

Comment: @soneedu Not quite. regex101 gives only the raw regex. Implementing this in code doesn't necessarily mean you'll put it exactly as it is there.